# Can Hana only allow user to view certain row of a view, if a condition is met

Tags: hana, hana-studio

I am wondering if the following is achievable with Hana. I want to create a role/analyticPrivilege/user such that, the user can only view a specific set of rows of a view if a condition about the row is met.

Let's say I am having a view `DEMO_VIEW`, and here is what it looks like.

```
| foo   | bar   | location |
|-------|-------|----------|
| foo_0 | bar_0 | US       |
| foo_1 | bar_1 | US       |
| foo_2 | bar_2 | CA       |
```

I want to create a role such that the user can view all rows where the `location` field == `"US"`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that’s possible in a straightforward way:
use **SAP HANA analytic privileges** and assign it to users/roles accordingly.